# Laravel: Set old checked checkbox with pivot tables

Tags: php, laravel

I dont know how to check `old` value with pivot tables. Am building ecommerce platform and each product category can have many stores. During creation new category i select only one store and after submit sleceted store is unchecked.

**What i try**

```
    <!-- Show only on update and all works good -->
    
    @if(isset($category))
        @foreach($stores as $store)
            <div class="form-check">
                @if($category->stores()->pluck('store.id')->contains($store->id))
                    <input type="checkbox" name="stores[]" checked value="{{ $store->id }}">
                @else
                    <input type="checkbox" name="stores[]"  value="{{ $store->id }}">
                @endif
                <label class="form-check-label" for="category_status_field">{{ $store->name }}</label>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    @else
    
        <!-- Show only on create -->
    
        @foreach($stores as $store)
            <div class="form-check">

               <!-- Here is problem -->

                <input type="checkbox" name="stores[]" {{ old('stores') == $store->categories()->pluck('category.id')->contains($store->id) ? 'checked' : '' }}  value="{{ $store->id }}">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="category_status_field">{{ $store->name }}</label>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    @endif
@endif
```

**Models**

```
class Store extends Model
{
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'category_store', 'store_id');
    }
}

class Category extends Model
{
    public function stores()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Store::class, 'category_store', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

**I also try**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="stores[]" {{ old('stores[$store->id]') == $store->id ? 'checked' : '' }}  value="{{ $store->id }}">
```

I dont understand how to check what checkbox is checked and with what to match to show `checked`.

Thanks

Comment: Note: The posted duplicate doesn't contain a 1:1 solution for your question, but there are lots of answers that show similar approaches 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a couple issues, the first of which is an `N+1` issue, where you're loading every associated `store.id` on every iteration of your `foreach()` loop. Let's fix that first.

In your Controller that renders this view, define the following:

```php
public function edit($categoryId) {
  $category = Category::findOrFail($categoryId);
  
  return view('categories.edit', [
    'category' => $category,
    'stores' => Store::all(), // or similar
    'storeIds' => $category->stores->pluck('id')
  ]);
}
```

If you're using `Route Model Binding`, you can skip that and simply do:

```php
public function edit(Category $category) { 
  return view('categories.edit', [
    'category' => $category,
    'stores' => Store::all(), // or similar
    'storeIds' => $category->stores->pluck('id')
  ]);
}
```

Now, you can reference `$storeIds` in your view. You can then use the `@checked` property (available in Laravel `9.x`)

```html
@foreach($stores as $store)
  <div class="form-check">
    <input type="checkbox" name="stores[]" @checked((old() ? collect(old('stores', []))->contains($store->id) : $storeIds->contains($store->id))) value="{{ $store->id }}">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="category_status_field">{{ $store->name }}</label>
  </div>
@endforeach
```

This will check both the `old()` values (from session redirect), or `$storeIds` to see if it contains each `$store->id`, and if it does, will mark the input as `checked.

For reference:

[`@checked` Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#additional-attributes)

Comment: Thanks for replay! I see now few mistakes in my code. But `store.id` if i not define `store` before `id` i get sql error `id is ambiguous`

Comment: Yup, but that's only if you're using `->stores()`, which is a SQL query. `->stores` is a `Collection`, so `->stores->pluck('id')` is correct. You can use `->stores()->pluck('store.id')` if you want, as you're working with a single record; up to you 

Answer (score 1):

**Problem sloved**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="stores[]" {{ is_array(old('stores')) && in_array($store->id, old('stores'))  ? 'checked ' : '' }}  value="{{ $store->id }}">
```